# upgraded unity to unity 2017 and games are now glitchy

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I recently upgraded to unity 2017 from unity 5.1 to get the 'service' tab, however players in the game blink (especially on the editor). Is there a quick fix to this, or should I downgrade, and if so, to which version?

Answer (score 1):

If you downgrade, glitches will stay. Same happened to me and after I downgrade it got a lot messy. So, dont upgrade if you have a project in another version and unity allows you to do that. I had a project in unity3d while i started another project in unity5. You can have both versions.

To save your project (if you dont have a back-up), scripts are not the problem but the editor and configurations are glitchy. So creating a new project and adding your scripts, 3d objects etc. Should fix it

Comment: Ok, thanks very much Samed. In the future, when upgrading unity, is there a quicker fix than this, or would you say that this is the best solution?